# Armor and ranger-variant barbarians?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature, ranger, barbarian

When using this [Unearthed Arcana variant](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/variant/classes/variantCharacterClasses.htm#barbarian), does the barbarian lose combat style mastery if they don medium armor? Does UA expand on this any more than the few lines offered in the SRD?

> **Gain**
>
> Favored enemy (as ranger); archery combat style, improved archery combat style, and archery combat style mastery (as ranger).
>
> **Lose**
>
> Rage, greater rage, indomitable will, tireless rage, mighty rage.

Comment: Just, because it’s worth noting: this is a *really* bad trade. Favored Enemy is almost entirely forgettable, and you could get those feats normally or by multiclassing. Whirling Frenzy alone does way more for an archer-barbarian than this does.

Comment: @KRyan agreed, I went with whirling frenzy. Just wanted to understand the options because I was considering it for an NPC

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### The ranger feature works just like it does for a ranger.

> These variants simply swap one or more of that class's features for one or more class features of another class. A class feature gained works just as it did for its original class, including the level at which it is gained and any other effects, except as noted below. (UA 59)

So yes: the barbarian loses all benefits of his combat style when wearing medium or heavy armor, because that's how it works for a ranger in the same situation.